# Ansible uri module authorization don't work as expected

Tags: automation, ansible, devops

i'm try to create kibana space through ansible uri module
here is my task

```
- name: Create altynorda kibana space
  uri:
    url: '{{ kibana_altynorda_url }}/api/spaces/space'
    method: POST
    body:
      {"id":"altynorda","name":"altynorda","description":"plati za parkovku","color":"#aabbcc","initials":"MK","disabledFeatures":["timelion","canvas"]}
    body_format: json
    headers:
      kbn-xsrf: 'true'
      Content-Type: 'application/json'
    url_username: elastic
    url_password: poshelnaxyi
  when:
    - first_host|default(false)|bool
    - '"altynorda" not in altynorda_spaces_result'
  delegate_to: localhost
```

so when i launch this task through ansible uri module the Kibana told error

```
FAILED! => {"cache_control": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"statusCode\":401,\"error\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"Unauthorized\"}", "content_length": "66", "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Wed, 07 Apr 2021 09:12:24 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "json": {"error": "Unauthorized", "message": "Unauthorized", "statusCode": 401}
```

but when i do this through plain cURL, it accepted

```
curl -u elastic:poshelnaxyi -X POST "https://kibana.kz/api/spaces/space" -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'

{

  "id": "altynorda",

  "name": "altynorda",

  "description" : "plati za parkovku",

  "color": "#aabbcc",

  "initials": "MK",

  "disabledFeatures": ["timelion", "canvas"]

}

'

{"id":"altynorda","name":"altynorda","description":"plati za parkovku","color":"#aabbcc","initials":"MK","disabledFeatures":["timelion","canvas"]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try adding the option

```
force_basic_auth: yes
```

I usually have to add this option for the reason in the docs
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-force_basic_auth

Answer (score 1):

Maybe main problem in your password, blet?

```
...
  url_password: poshelnaxyi
...
```